# access ARP table without root in Android

Tags: android, root, wireless, arp, wifi

I am recently working on a Android project that requires to access the ARP table. One of the requirement is to avoid any methods that need a rooted device. So, my question is: 
    is there any way to access the ARP table in android without rooting the device?

Currently I have found that most of the approaches use the /proc/net/arp for the ARP table access which requires root permission, and I am not sure if this is the only way.

Comment: Did you find a different way to acces ARP table?

Comment: How do you access it as *root*??? When I run the `arp` command normally it works, but when I `su` so I can use the `-s` option and try to run it I get "arp: inaccessible or not found"!!!

Answer (score 2):

I can access ARP table without root. Here is my code:

```
string GetMACAddressviaIP(string ipAddr)
{
    string result = "";
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << "/proc/net/arp";
    string loc = ss.str();

    ifstream in(loc);
    if(!in)
    {
        printf("open %s failed\n",loc.c_str());
        return result;
    }

    string line;
    while(getline(in, line)){
        if(strstr(line.c_str(), ipAddr.c_str()))
        {
            const char *buf = strstr(line.c_str(), ":") - 2;
            int counter = 0;
            stringstream ss;
            while(counter < 17)
            {
                ss << buf[counter];
                counter++;
            }
            result = ss.str();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details... What language is this? How do you execute it on android? ......

Comment: This language is C++. I was using NDK while developing Android project. JNI allows access to C/C++ code.

Comment: @RobinDavies is there any alternative solution Im stuck, cant find way to access arp file starting  android 10,

Comment: I ended up using UUIDs associated with devices other than routers on the network to identify the network.

Comment: @RobinDavies can you provide more details?

Answer (score 2):

For better understanding, using Java language, you can retrieve the ARP table in android as:

```
    BufferedReader br = null;
    ArrayList<ClientScanResult> result = new ArrayList<ClientScanResult>();

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(line);
    }
    }Catch(Exception e){
    }finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend something like the following for Java. This combines the answers for the other two. It's not tested, so it might need some tweaks, but you get the idea.

```
public String getMacAddressForIp(final String ipAddress) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains(ipAddress)) {
                final int macStartIndex = line.indexOf(":") - 2;
                final int macEndPos = macStartIndex + 17;
                if (macStartIndex >= 0 && macEndPos < line.length()) {
                    return line.substring(macStartIndex, macEndPos);
                } else {
                    Log.w("MyClass", "Found ip address line, but mac address was invalid.");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("MyClass", "Exception reading the arp table.", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to previous answers a "no coding" solution is to install a linux terminal emulator on your device and use the arp -a command to view the arp table.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example you can separate the complete command to another line in a code block, and add guidance how to install that emulator.

Comment: On Android 13 this gives `/proc/net/arp: Permission denied`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that an application has not been able to access the arp file since Android 10. [link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#proc-net-filesystem)