# How can we access ARP table in Android 11?

Tags: android

I want to find the devices with mac address from ARP table but in android 11 we can't access ARP table

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
string GetMACAddressviaIP(string ipAddr)
{
    string result = "";
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << "/proc/net/arp";
    string loc = ss.str();

    ifstream in(loc);
    if(!in)
    {
        printf("open %s failed\n",loc.c_str());
        return result;
    }

    string line;
    while(getline(in, line)){
        if(strstr(line.c_str(), ipAddr.c_str()))
        {
            const char *buf = strstr(line.c_str(), ":") - 2;
            int counter = 0;
            stringstream ss;
            while(counter < 17)
            {
                ss << buf[counter];
                counter++;
            }
            result = ss.str();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

If this doesn't work, read more about it here:
[access ARP table without root in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660034/access-arp-table-without-root-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for you response,
we can't access arp table in android 11. so how to get macAddress without arp table?
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/arp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)